# How to use Chance js in Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, chancejs

I can't get [Chance js](http://chancejs.com/) to work in my vue project. I install and import it locally and it give this error when I try to access `chance.paragraph()` in the .vue file.

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_chance___default.a.paragraph is not a function"
```

Running `chance.paragraph()` in the console does work though

Comment: The question is, have you instantiate new Chance object with `new` keyword ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you include it? sourcecode seems to give the answer:

[image]

Edit: i thought you can use it directly but the website says otherwise using nodejes:

```
// Load Chance
var Chance = require('chance');

// Instantiate Chance so it can be used
var chance = new Chance();

// Use Chance here.
var paragraph = chance.paragraph();
```

Comment: I didn't instantiate chance. It works now. Thanks :)